# How to fix Wordpress text field which is not displaying properly?

Tags: wordpress

I need help with fixing width of the dropdown field.

Please look at the pick up date field on the below URL.This field is not getting displayed properly.

https://ravenwoodband.com/store/donation-for-marching-band-trees/

How can I increase the width of the field so it shows the complete text?

I am using WP 6.2.3
Theme : Dance Studio

Can I use custom CSS to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show complete text then try adding this

```
select#ec_option1 {
    height: 100%;
}
```

[image: Adding first code will look like this]

Also If you want to make it in full width with readable text then try adding this

```
select#ec_option1 {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
```

[image: Adding first code will look like this]

Also add important if it is not working.
Hope this work for you.

Comment: Thank you so much. This fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of your problem is the height that set on your selection field. You can fix it by adding the default value of height in CSS which is auto. If it did'nt work try to add !important after auto.

```html
select#ec_option1 {
    height: auto;
}
```